# How to use EXISTS and IN with the subquery in Linq

Tags: linq

Could you please help me to convert this to Linq where we have EXISTS and IN for sub query.

```
 Select * From laqTasks where siteid=1 
and Exists(Select 1 from laqTasks where room=1) and duty=1
and Room IN (SELECT roomid FROM laqPmsTasks WHERE siteid =2)
```

Thanks,
N.ShanthaKumar.

Comment: A good start would be to find an O/R mapper that supports LINQ and create a class model that maps to the database.

Comment: LINQ isn't SQL and doesn't query databases. It's a general purpose query language. It's not Embedded SQL either. What are you trying to do? Are you using an ORM like EF Core? In that case you're looking for `Task` objects whose `Room` or `Rooms` properties contain specific items

Comment: EF Core deals with objects, not tables and rows. You can use EF Core and LINQ to search for a `PmTask` object whose `Room` relation has a `siteid` with 2 with `context.PmTasks.Where(t=>t.Room.SiteID==2)`.

Comment: SO is not free SQL to LINQ translation service. Show your attempts and we will help you to move into right direction. Actually you are asking about LINQ basics. Learn LINQ first and EF Core Query documentation.

Comment: Side note: You appear to have two independent references to `laqTasks`. The inner `Exists(Select 1 from laqTasks where room=1)` will either always be true (likely) or always be false, and will not affect which `laqTasks` are included in the outer select results.

Comment: Perhaps my [SQL to LINQ Recipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49245160/sql-to-linq-with-multiple-join-count-and-left-join/49245786#49245786) might help you.